# Get value of input field automatically to html jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to read out a value from an input field (id="leweb_value_99") to an html tag (p, span or div).

The value should be read out when the value changes in the input field, and the input field `leweb_value_99` will be hidden if it works.

My code so far:

```js
   $(document).ready(function() {
  
  // BÜROFLÄCHEN
        $('#leweb_value_1').change(function() { // WENN SELECT CHANGED
            $('#leweb_value_1_input').val(''); // TEXTFELD LEEREN
            var selectValue = $(this).val()*0.2; // VALUE AUS SELECT
            $('#leweb_value_1_input').val(selectValue); // TEXTFELD FÜLLEN
   leweb_price();
        }); 
  
  // SANITÄRFLÄCHEN
        $('#leweb_value_2').change(function() { // WENN SELECT CHANGED
            $('#leweb_value_2_input').val(''); // TEXTFELD LEEREN
            var selectValue = $(this).val()*0.45; // VALUE AUS SELECT
            $('#leweb_value_2_input').val(selectValue); // TEXTFELD FÜLLEN
   leweb_price();
        }); 
  
  // KÜCHENFLÄCHEN
        $('#leweb_value_3').change(function() { // WENN SELECT CHANGED
            $('#leweb_value_3_input').val(''); // TEXTFELD LEEREN
            var selectValue = $(this).val()*0.45; // VALUE AUS SELECT
            $('#leweb_value_3_input').val(selectValue); // TEXTFELD FÜLLEN
   leweb_price();
        });   

  // REINIGUNGSINTERVALLE
        $('#leweb_value_5').change(function() { // WENN SELECT CHANGED
            $('#leweb_value_5_input').val(''); // TEXTFELD LEEREN
            var selectValue = $(this).val(); // VALUE AUS SELECT
            $('#leweb_value_5_input').val(selectValue); // TEXTFELD FÜLLEN
   leweb_price();
        }); 

  function leweb_price() {
    var a = parseInt($('#leweb_value_1_input').val());
    var b = parseInt($('#leweb_value_2_input').val());
    var c = parseInt($('#leweb_value_3_input').val());
    var z = parseInt($('#leweb_value_5_input').val());
    var total = (a+b+c)*z;
    if(!isNaN(total)){
      $('#leweb_value_99').val(total);
    }
  }  
    
 });
```

```html
  <form id="ajax-contact-form" method="post">

  <p>Büroflächen m² Anzahl</p>
  <input type="text" name="leweb_value_1" id="leweb_value_1" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="leweb_value_1_input" id="leweb_value_1_input" value="0" />

  <p>Sanitärflächen m² Anzahl</p>
  <input type="text" name="leweb_value_2" id="leweb_value_2" />
  <input type="hidden" name="leweb_value_2_input" id="leweb_value_2_input" value="0" />

  <p>Küchenflächen m² Anzahl</p>
  <input type="text" name="leweb_value_3" id="leweb_value_3" />
  <input type="hidden" name="leweb_value_3_input" id="leweb_value_3_input" value="0" />

  <p>Reinigungsintervalle</p>
   <select id="leweb_value_5" class="leweb_value_5" name="leweb_value_5" value="0" />
    <option value="">Anzahl waehlen</option>
    <option value="1">1x pro Woche</option>
    <option value="2">2x pro Woche</option>
    <option value="3">3x pro Woche</option>
    <option value="4">4x pro Woche</option>
    <option value="5">5x pro Woche</option>
    <option value="6">6x pro Woche</option>
    <option value="7">7x pro Woche</option>
     </select>
   <input type="hidden" id="leweb_value_5_input" name="leweb_value_5_input" value="1" /><br> 
   
  <p class="price-box"><strong>Preis in € (pro Woche)</strong></p>
  <p class="price-input weekly">
   <input class="price-field" type="text" id="leweb_value_99" name="leweb_value_99" value="0" /> 
  </p>
```

Comment: And what is the problem? Are all inputs populated when you run the function leweb_price ??? because if any of those values are not set, it would not work, you would have to set the value to 0 if the input field is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are already updating #leweb_value_99 you can update an HTML tag in the same function. 
Add a span to the containing p tag and then you will be able to replace the HTML with your value each time the function is called.

```
<p class="price-input weekly">
<span></span>
        <input class="price-field" type="text" id="leweb_value_99" name="leweb_value_99" value="0" />
    </p>
```

Update the JavaScript to this

```
if(!isNaN(total)){
              $('#leweb_value_99').val(total);
$('.price-input.weekly span').html(total)
            }
```

You should also set your input field to hidden.